# jQuery hover in Wordpress: fading in a hidden div while fading out the “default” one

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, hover, fadein

I'm having problems using jQuery's hover feature with the Wordpress loop. Everytime I hover one image (there are 6), they all fade instead of just the single image. Please help.

Here's my code:

```
<?php query_posts('showposts=6&cat=-4'); ?>
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); if ( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; update_post_caches($posts); ?>

<li class="show1">

<?php $thumb = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thumb', true); ?>

<a href="#" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" class="show"><?php echo$thumb; ?></a>

<div class="hide">

    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    <a class="view_project" href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">View Project »</a>
</div>
</li>
```

and my Javascript is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$('li.show1').children('.hide').hide();

$('li.show1').hover(function() {
    $(this).children('a.show').fadeOut('slow')
        .end().children('.hide').fadeIn('slow');
}, function() {
    $(this).children('a.show').fadeIn('slow')
        .end().children('.hide').fadeOut('slow');
});
});
</script>
```

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `$('a.show')` with `$(this).children('a.show')` -- this will restrict your fadeOut to the anchor links inside the `li` that was hovered over.

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Now only one is being selected but the fadeIn and fadeOut effects aren't working, any suggestions?

Comment: Could it be because both your `hover` callback functions are identical, instead of reciprocal?

Comment: I thought so too, but I changed it (edited above) and nothing happened.

Comment: Edited my answer. Is this the effect you wanted? http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/fqqYe/

Comment: I did notice the hovering effect just wears off after the first hover. I've looked for ways to keep jQuery effects repeating but no luck, any suggestions?

Comment: @Mauricio I don't understand what you mean. You might want to open a new question if you're having new issues.